# Python: Shift time series so they all match at a given y value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing my own code to analyse/visualise COVID-19 data from the European CDC.
https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv'

I've got a simple code to extract the data and make plots with cumulative deaths against time, and am trying to add functionality.

My aim is something like the attached graph, with all countries time shifted to match at (in this case the 5th death) I want to make a general bit of code to shift countries to match at the 'n'th death. 
https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/covid-confirmed-deaths-since-5th-death

The current way I'm trying to do this is to have a maze of "if group is 'country' shift by ..." terms.

Where ... is a lookup to find the date for the particular 'country' when there were 'n' deaths, and to interpolate fractional dates where appropriate.

i.e. currently deaths are assigned as 00:00 day/month, but the data can be shifted by 2/3 a day as below.

datetime       cumulative deaths
00:00  15/02  80
00:00  16/02  110

my '...' should give 16:00 15/02

I'm working on this right now but it doesn't feel very efficient and I'm sure there must be a much simpler way that I'm not seeing.

Essentially despite copious googling I can't seem to find a simple way of automatically shifting a bunch of timeseries to match at a particular y value, which feels like it should have some built-in functionality, i.e. a Lookup with interpolation.

```
####Live url (I've downloaded my own csv and been calling that for code development)
url = 'https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv'

dataraw = pd.read_csv(url)

#extract relevanty colums
data = dataraw.loc[:,["dateRep","countriesAndTerritories","deaths"]]

####convert date format
data['dateRep'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dateRep'],dayfirst=True)

####sort by date
data = data.sort_values(["dateRep"],ascending=True)

data['cumdeaths'] = data.groupby(['countriesAndTerritories']).cumsum()




##### limit to countries with cumulative deaths > 500

data = data.groupby('countriesAndTerritories').filter(lambda x:x['cumdeaths'].max() >500)

###### remove China from data for now as it doesn't match so well with dates
data = data.groupby('countriesAndTerritories').filter(lambda x:(x['countriesAndTerritories'] != "China").any())

##### only recent dates
data = data[data['dateRep'] > '2020-03-01']

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby('country')` and the [pd.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function to add a column which will set every row with the date in which its country hit the nth death.

Then you can do a vectorized subtraction of the date column and the new column to get the number of days.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the groupby('country') and vectorized subtraction, but I'm not really sure about the pd.transform.

If the series goes .....,80,110,... Then I need a way to interpolate a fractional date in between the points.

Comment: If you add code to your question or an example of the dataframe data I can add code to my answer to explain myself better.